# copying the tail part of a string into another array in C, no reference no pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string

let' say I have

```
char *one = "1234567890ab"
```

I want would like to copy everything after the 10th char into another array in C. But I would like to copy it, I do not want a pointer pointing to it, so that if I modify the array holding "ab", nothing happens to the original one.

if I do something like:

```
char help[10];
for(i=0; ((char help[i] = *(one + n + i)) != '\0'; ++i);
```

char help will get the last two chars but still acts as a pointer so if go

```
char help[1] = 'z';
```

the original string becomes

```
"1234567890az"
```

how can I prevent this from happening thank you

edit: I tried strcpy and it did not work, still produced a pointer.

Comment: no that doesn't work

Comment: Copy the `\0` character as well

Comment: What the ... is "produced a pointer" ???

Comment: Can we see a copy of your complete code that causes this problem, preferably stripped down to a nice short main()? The behavior you're describing doesn't make sense, so there may be a bug in the rest of your code that you've overlooked.

Comment: copy the '\0' character as well? what difference would that make? the point is that the array acts as a pointer, I want to be able to modify the array, and that code does copy '\0' as well

Comment: okay pasting the code

Comment: Strcpy works fine. Just `strcpy(help, one + 10);`.

Comment: Yep, the `strcpy()` approach works fine (as would the above loop, after fixing a syntax error or two): https://ideone.com/Xam0OC

Comment: Right, misunderstood the question. But it still make a little sense.

Comment: From everything I just read (and I had to read some of the phrases twice due to mild bewilderment), my only advice is to stop thinking you know what you're talking about regarding pointers and arrays in C. Study them (again).

Comment: "char help will get the last two chars but still acts as a pointer so if go `char help[1] = z;` the original string becomes '1234567890az'".  Sorry, I do not believe you.

Comment: whozCraig I know about pointers believe me. What part of my explanation did not make sense to you?

Comment: A (fixed, compilable) version of the loop in the question, which also works as expected: https://ideone.com/j0Abfg

Comment: Prove with a working example. Better with ideone.com

Comment: thanks paul maybe then there is something else wrong with my code, at least you could unterstand the question, unlike some arrogant people here, who love to blame before they read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcpy` cannot “produce a pointer [to `one`]” out of `help` when `help` is defined as an array of `char`. It is independent of the original string. There is an error somewhere else in your code, but at the moment you are not showing enough code to tell what it is. However, the following code:

```
char *one = "1234567890ab";
char help[10];
(void) strcpy(help, one + 10);
(void) printf("one = %s\nhelp = %s\n", one, help);
help[1] = 'z';
(void) printf("one = %s\nhelp = %s\n", one, help);
```

Produces the output:

```
one = 1234567890ab
help = ab
one = 1234567890ab
help = az
```

Comment: yeah there is something else wrong, still cannot find what it is, but thanks

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy` is indeed the way to go. This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char *one = "1234567890ab";
    char two[10];

    strcpy(two, one + 10);
    two[1] = 'z';

    printf("one: %s\n", one);
    printf("two: %s\n", two);

    return 0;
}
```

will generate this output:

```
one: 1234567890ab
two: az

Success time: 0 memory: 2008 signal:0
```

See this [example](http://ideone.com/kD8Rcb).